How to build my knowledge base so that I can come up with research ideas?
I am beginning my career in research. I recently joined IIT Kharagpur as a researcher under a professor. I am thinking about publishing research papers, but I cant think of any ideas. I lack the advanced knowledge base to come up with unique ideas on the field.
I know that I want to research AI and that to about Computer Vision in Healthcare. So I know the broad area, I know how to write programs in the field. I have started to read research papers as my professor tells me to. But my professor isn't in medical image processing.
How do I explore my field and get to a stage, where I can make connections or innovations that I can research. How did you do it. Did I read more papers, do I watch more tutorials or lecture etc. Going to the next stage has been frustrating and confusing.
Thanks in Advance

I'll still stand by my answer to https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/192470/how-to-find-research-gap. Build a circle of collaborators, globally if necessary. And note that that question, also linked by @Ben, was closed.

You want to ‘[publish] research papers, but […] cant think of any ideas.’ Why are you interested in publishing research papers?

I actually had 3-4 ideas while working for a company but on arriving at IIT, The prof said that the the domain was outdated and not worth publishing, but he said it was interesting. So I know I have the potential but not the base

There may be different opinions on this, but I feel that the best place to start is to look at literature reviews and mapping studies. These often give a very good overview of the field and may also identify potential research gaps. At the start of my PhD, I did a systematic review. While this was very insightful, it was also incredibly time-consuming - hence why I would recommend looking at literature reviews that have already been written. After identifying where others feel there are gaps in the research, take a closer look at what research has been done to close those gaps. This will help you avoid making a contribution to a research gap that has already been done before. It's worth noting too, that I think a problem that's common among early career researchers is what they consider a novel contribution. Remember, it does not have to be ground-breaking. I would suggest making an incremental improvement on something that has been done before, or, identifying a flaw in other research and proposing an alternative to address that problem. Good luck!

Also replicating a study can be a good place to start. Unfortunately, publishing such a study can be difficult in some fields. So if you want to do that look for journals in your field that publishes replications. If you cannot find one, then this is probably not worth it.
